# left shift Operator cpp

Tags: c++, binary-operators

i found this definition of CPP array in and competitive programming editorial

```
long long s1[1<<10][1<<10],s2[1<<10][1<<10]
```

why it is written like this we can simply write it like

```
 s1[1024][1024]
```

is there any reason behind this ?

Comment: you will find many wtfs in competetive code. They tend to use stuff that you would not use anywhere else, for "convenience" or whatever

Comment: anyhow, only the author can tell you why they wrote it like they did

Comment: Sidenote: Those are _left_ shifts.

Comment: BTW: If you're quoting something, give proper attribution as well! In this case, a link to where you found this would be in place, at least. Maybe that could explain it when you a bit more context. That said, the general rule is that all relevant context should be included in the question.

Comment: It's a really bad idea to put 1024x1024 matrix on stack.

Answer (score 5):

Constant bit shifts such as `1u << N` are generally written to emphasise that the number is the Nth power of 2.

"[Magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming))" should be avoided, and small numbers like 1 and 10 are "less magical" than large numbers. I would still recommend using a named constant to clarify why 10 was used specifically.

Comment: That's still a magic number. If you took it seriously, you'd assign it to a constant, of course with a proper, speaking name and perhaps additional comments. That said, some usually smart people believe that powers of two are magically the only proper sizes for a buffer, which is rather known as cargo cult programming. ;)

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Cache line sizes, cache sizes, page sizes, block sizes are nearly always powers of two. It's often most efficient for a buffer to either not exceed or to not fall short of those thresholds or to evenly subdivide them. A power of two buffer size is a reasonable choice until you have evidence that it's not. For circular buffers, powers of two allow you to use faster remainder operations (bitmasks).

Answer (score 2):

`1<<10` is a shorthand for "Bit 10 is set, all other bits are zero". You find this construct very often around lowlevel code, where powers of 2 or bits are important.

`1<<10 == 0x400 == 010000000000`